# Cordova: Is it possible to have different start page (content) or the config.xml for each platforms?

Tags: cordova

I am trying to build an application that switches it's layout based on platform - meaning that the application should use hamburger menu based layout for android while showing the bottom navigation on iOS. I am planning to abstract this layout part in the `index.html` and use different versions for different platforms. Now my questions are:

1. Is it possible to switch between the content based on platform?
2. Is it possible to have different config.xml for different platforms?
3. What are the other solutions to this layout switching problem?

Answer (score 0):

With Cordovas plugin Device you can access which platform the app is running on and then you can write some custom code depending on which platform the user is using https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-device/#deviceplatform

You should not use different config.xml files. If you want to specify preferences or other elements specific to a particular platform you should use the platform attribute in the config.xml https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/#platform